# MEANJS.org folder structure

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs, angular1.6

I've inherited a MEANJS.org project that I need to do, and the folder structure is so complex - I'm really struggling to understand what's going on!

I've attached an image of a standard module's files. Would someone please explain to me what each one does. I know some of them, which I'll list below.

[image]

- What do the config files do?
- I know what the controller.js does.
- I know what the CSS does.
- What does the service.js one do? Is this Express?
- I know what the view.html does.
- What does the module.js one do? Is this Node.js?
- Then the only one I know under the server is the routes.js. I have no
  idea what the others do.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: I'd say open them and see?  The folder structure is standard, but the contents of those files can vary wildly from implementer to implementer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've been on the project for a few weeks and I'm still not sure how they all relate to each other. What do you mean "standard", standard in relation to what?

Comment: Meanjs generator kicks out certain stuff as a template, but that doesn’t mean the previous developer used them as intended